Mapping monthly max mean temperature
I need to map and determine the monthly mean max temperature for my study area between 2013 and 2023. The following code works, but I am confident that the result is not the monthly mean during the period.
How can I change it to produce a TIFF of mean of max temperature?
Map.addLayer(geometry)
print(geometry)
print()
Map.centerObject(geometry, 6);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2013-01-01', '2023-12-01'))
                                    .mean();
var maximumTemperature = dataset.select('tmmx');
var maximumTemperatureVis = {
  min: -300.0,
  max: 300.0,
  palette: [
    '1a3678', '2955bc', '5699ff', '8dbae9', 'acd1ff', 'caebff', 'e5f9ff',
    'fdffb4', 'ffe6a2', 'ffc969', 'ffa12d', 'ff7c1f', 'ca531a', 'ff0000',
    'ab0000'
  ],
};
Map.addLayer(maximumTemperature.clip(geometry), maximumTemperatureVis, 'Maximum Temperature');
var final = dataset.clip(geometry)
var MeansOfFeatures = final.reduceRegions({
  collection: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  //scale: 250,
});

print(ee.Feature(MeansOfFeatures.first()))
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: final.double(),
  description: 'Max_Temprerature',
  //scale: 10,
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
});

